# ::after element not showing on a page, but is visible in live-server page

Tags: html, css, github, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I've got a ::after element on label for a checkbox input.

Everything works on live-server in an editor, element is visible, :checked animation works, everything is ok.

I pushed the code on a repository on github and when I open the page, ::after element isn't showing up.

Here's HTML:

```
    <li class="main__list-item">
         <div class="main__list-item-container">
              <input type="checkbox" id="question-1" class="main__list-question"></input>
              <label for="question-1" class="main__label">How many team members can I invite?</label>
              <p class="main__list-answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. 
                                           There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan</p>
         </div>
   </li>
```

Here's CSS:

```
.main__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: var(--color-text-secondary);
    transition: all 0.4s;
    width: 100%; }
    .main__label::after {
      content: url("/img/icon-arrow-down.svg");
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      transition: all 0.4s; }
    .main__label:hover {
      color: var(--color-text-main); }

 .main__list-question {
appearance: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none; }
   .main__list-question:checked ~ .main__label::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg); }
   .main__list-question:checked ~ .main__list-answer {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    color: var(--color-text-tertiary);
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out; }
   .main__list-question:checked + .main__label {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.4rem; }
```

even without visible ::after element, all animations work still, font-size changing, p element showing and etc.

[This is from vs code live-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrUg6.png)

[This is from github page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKkKh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem ist the image Path:
[image]

you have to change the URL:

```
    content: url(../img/icon-arrow-down.svg);
```